# How to add data into list<> from lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda, entity-framework-5

I need help to add data from lambda expression query to list.

```
var Emplist = context.employee.tolist().firstordefault(e => e.id= empid && e.name = empname)
```

Now wants result into generic list

```
list<Emplist> emplist = context.employee.tolist().firstordefault(e => e.id= empid && e.name = empname)
```

I get an error.

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` returns just that - one item (or `null`). If you want a `List<T>` then use `.Where(e => e.id == empid && e.name == empname).ToList()`

Comment: @user3085836 and make sure to use the `.ToList()` after the `Where` clause, not before: `context.employee.Where(e => e.id = empid && e.name = empname).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Emplist> emplist = context.employee.Where(e=>e.id= empid && e.name=empname).ToList();
```